# How to move a shape without selecting it?

Tags: excel, vba

How can I move any shape in a sheet without selecting it?

If I use:

```
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 18")).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft -76"
```

it appears an edition border around the shape.

Answer (score 1):

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture 18").IncrementLeft -76
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what i wanted. Thanks.

Comment: How to avoid activating the sheet?

Comment: @Ivan - Not sure how I can answer that without any context.  If you don't want to activate the sheet then don't activate it?

Answer (score 0):

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set s = Worksheets("sheet1").Shapes(1)
s.Left = 100
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```